# Printing (or pdf) of FULL report including all jpg files

Tags: sharing, software-recommendations, myheritage.com

I have My Heritage on my laptop and have done a lot of research over the years.  Have stored a lot of jpg files of census reports, draft registrations, new paper articles etc. under the appropriate family members.

Am doing all this for my children and grandchildren.  Need to know how I can get all of this - a tree o ancestors plus a report that include all of the attachments for each person.

My Heritage doesn't do it.  Don't think ancestry.com does it.  Can't tell if 'gramps project' does it.

Answer (score 7):

My main software is Calico Pie's Family Historian 6, which contains among its many features the capability to print booklets. You can see some screenshots on the **[tour page](http://www.family-historian.co.uk/tour)**.

[image]

See the FHUG's Knowledge Base article: [Report Content, Media, Format and Layout](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/doku.php?id=how_to:report_content_multimedia_format_layout&s[]=book) and other related articles in the wiki for some how-to articles.

Calico Pie says the book creation functions allow you to have "a mix of auto-generated chapters and your own ‘free text’ pages and chapters".

For producing your own text, I highly recommend [Scrivener](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php), the writing studio software from Literature and Latte; it is available for several different operating systems, and is designed to be used in conjunction with other programs.  For example, a writer might do the preliminary drafts in Scrivener and then send the output selected in compile to Word or another program for final formatting.

Writers who use Scrivener for Genealogy include:

- Lynn Palermo, the author of [Scrivener for the Family Historian](http://www.familyhistorywritingstudio.com/) (on YouTube: [Introduction to using Scrivener for Genealogy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4t7Rwgn6G4I))
- Lisa Alzo -- see her guest post at Lisa Louise Cooke's site Genealogy Gems: [Scrivener Software for Writing Family History](https://lisalouisecooke.com/2016/03/scrivener-for-genealogy-writing-family-history/) and on the Legacy Blog: [Three Reasons You Should be Using Scrivener to Write Your Family History](http://news.legacyfamilytree.com/legacy_news/2016/10/scrivener-to-write-your-family-history.html); webinars in the [Legacy Family Tree Webinars Library](https://familytreewebinars.com/intermediate_page.php?diply_nm=scrivener)
- [Denise May Levenick](http://thefamilycurator.com/), who presented talks on using Scrivener for Genealogy during [RootsTech2014](http://static1.1.sqspcdn.com/static/f/406579/24647059/1396222835767/scrivener-handout.pdf?token=HVlVMHWJCEIdCs48bcgxjnVdH18%3D).

Other resources:

- *The Disciplined Genealogist*: [**Porting Genealogy Data to Word via Scrivener**](https://thedisciplinedgenealogist.com/2016/01/13/porting-genealogy-data-in-word-via-scrivener/)