# Software/service for informal genealogy book?

Tags: publishing, software-recommendations

Can anyone recommend a means of *informally* publishing a *short* family history that includes text, charts, and photos, for a non-family-researching audience?

This would be intended for an 80th birthday gift, for someone interested in history, but not necessarily the nuts & bolts of family history research. Ideally it would be around 30 pages with good-quality images- a sort of genealogy picture book!?

Answer (score 4):

I like the software Gramps to export my data in book format.
You can include graphs, images, etc. 
Pretty easy to use also.
Software is free and can be downloaded from [here](https://gramps-project.org/).
Also, see [Printing (or pdf) of FULL report including all jpg files](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12789/19) for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI- I've ended up putting together a 'photo book' using shutterfly.com. I haven't received the final product yet, but their online interface is pretty easy to use and it offers a lot of options for layout that include significant portions of text, and large two-page images. For the relationship charts, I just exported them from my genealogy software as jpg files and placed them in the book. It seems like a good way to share genealogical research with the immediate family in an engaging way.

Comment: Book has arrived- good quality and turned-around within one week from submission.